# How to print out instance of object that is stored in an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, tostring, instanceof

So I need to print out the different instances of the array. Using the code below. Everything in the array prints out even the portion of the array that is not filled with anything. If i add a break statement in each if statement it only prints the last instance of that array and not everything that that stored.

```
public static void display(ExampleA[] example)
{ 
    for(int pos = 0; pos < example.length; pos++) 
    {   
        output += "Example number " + (i + 1);
       if(example[pos] instanceof A)
        {
                output += example[pos].toString() + "\n\n";             
        }

        if(example[pos] instanceof B)
        {
            output += example[pos].toString() + "\n\n"; 
        }

    }
```

What I would like it to do is print out everything in the array grouped together by the instance. and not the whole array that is partially empty.

Comment: Provide a testcase. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: So, for example I run through the program and there is are 3 objects stored total in the array. I don't understand why all spaces in the array are printed out in the JOptionPane. And if I add a break statement only the last inputed of the instance prints out.

Comment: Array elements are never empty.  Are you trying to avoid elements that are `null`?  What does your class hierarchy look like?  What's in `casesA`?  What do you mean "grouped together by the instance"?  Also, it seems like you're having a terminology problem.  Please check the definitions of class, superclass, and instance.

Comment: You might want to look at [enhanced for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (at the bottom of the page). They make code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: If you provide the calling method of void display(ExampleA[] example) then we can reach what you want ....

Comment: yeah I am trying to avoid elements that are null. So what I mean by group by is that the each input is an instance of A or B. So if i have three inputs 2 is an instance of A and 1 is an Instance B. How do I print it out so that it prints out all instances of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `output` variables, one for the `A` instances and one for the `B` instances. Then you can append each instance to its corresponding output variables, and print out the output variables at the end. Here's an example using your code:

```
public static void display(ExampleA[] example)
{ 
    for(int pos = 0; pos < example.length; pos++) 
    {   
        if(example[pos] instanceof A)
        {
            outputA += "Example number " + (i + 1);
            outputA += example[pos].toString() + "\n\n";             
        }

        if(example[pos] instanceof B)
        {
            outputB += "Example number " + (i + 1);
            outputB += example[pos].toString() + "\n\n"; 
        }

    }

    System.out.println("A:\n" + outputA);
    System.out.println("B:\n" + outputB);
}
```

You should also look into using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to append the Strings, as it's much faster than using `+=`

Comment: Hey Greg! so this actually doesn't work. I does not print out all the instances.

Comment: I am so sorry greg I missed out a vital piece of information that may have caused the issue I need to number the array so I added output += "Number: " + (i + 1) + "\n"; which is causing the problem

Comment: So... are you still having a problem? If so, what?

Comment: Yes, When i try to number the examples it prints out the empty spaces for the array. I edited the code above!

Comment: If you want the numbers to only print out with each group, you can just move the appending of the number to inside the if statements. See my edited code.